# GUI user input through C

Tags: c, user-interface

I have a project (sort of) where I have to write a C program to take in user inputs and store it into a MySQL database for future retrieval.

Now, I have written the program for console mode.

I.e. it asks the user `please enter a name` and then the name entered by the user is stored in the database.

But, I have to do it in this way , like when the screen comes it will show

```
   name
   |--------|
   |--------|<- here the user will enter his name.
   |--------|
```

and, from here the name entered will be stored in a string variable.

I am not sure , but I think it is GUI programming.

I have no knowledge about GUI programming.

Unfortunately, I don't have much time to read a lot.

So, can you please point me to some tutorial or some resources or anything that is specifically aimed at this type of GUI programming.

I want to use the win32 API

Comment: "Unfortunately, I don't have much time to read a lot."  You need information, but it's not important enough for you to invest your time in getting it.  Changing your stance on learning a new library could spell the difference between success and failure.

Answer (score 2):

If it is ran in the console, it is not GUI programming.  If you are emulating GUI programming in the console (with text boxes, etc), it is call TUI (Text User Interface) programming.

On Unix/Linux systems one typically uses the new curses (aka "ncurses") library.  On Microsoft systems, I believe [the PDCurses library](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/) is the closest thing available.  Using them you can set up "text" windows which have height and width measured in characters (including text input fields).

If you don't need to simulate a window system in text, then just read and write lines to stdout and stdin.